# How to hide keyboard when bar button pressed in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I hide the keyboard when the user clicks on a bar button (shown in image).
How can I get the keyboard to resign on tap of the sidemenu icon in the navigation bar?

[image]

Comment: are you using SWRevealViewController ???

Comment: yes @jaydeep vyas

Comment: you can use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES]` as it is global keyboard dismissl in your - `(IBAction)revealToggle:(id)sender` inside your SWRevealViewController.m file

Comment: @Jaydeep Vyas can u explain brielfy

Comment: Tq it's worl like charm @Jaydeep Vyas

Comment: if you are begginer try the solution given by Nirav Kotecha below it works perfect for you

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

Swift 3.0:

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

you can write this line in **sidemenu icon button click event**.

Comment: if you have not create click event of the sidebar button than create it and write this code into click event of sidebar button.